# Openshift: User "system:serviceaccount:<project>:jenkins" can't create PV : RBAC: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "create" not found

Tags: jenkins, openshift, openshift-origin, jenkins-job-dsl, okd

Openshift/okd version: 3.11

I'm using jenkins-ephemeral app from the openshift catalog and using a buildconfig to create a pipeline. Reference: https://docs.okd.io/3.11/dev_guide/dev_tutorials/openshift_pipeline.html

When i start the pipeline, in one the stage of jenkins it needs to create a persistent volume, at that point im getting the following error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): persistentvolumes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:pipelineproject:jenkins" cannot create persistentvolumes at the cluster scope: RBAC: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "create" not found
```

I have tried giving the cluster-create role to service account jenkins with following command, still im getting the same error.

```
oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user create system:serviceaccount:pipelineproject:jenkins
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `PersistentVolume` is typically something that you should *not* be manually doing. You should ideally be relying on `PersistentVolumeClaims`. `PersistentVolumeClaims` are namespaced resources, that your service account should be able to create with the `edit` Role.

```sh
$ oc project pipelineproject
$ oc policy add-role-to-user edit -z jenkins
```

However, if it's required that you interact with `PersistentVolume` objects directly, there is a `storage-admin` ClusterRole that should be able to give your ServiceAccount the necessary permissions.

```sh
$ oc project pipelineproject
$ oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user storage-admin -z jenkins
```

Comment: You mentioned `PersistentVolume`'s should not be manually created, then how can it be created? Here i'm using a template to create both `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaims`. If suppose `PersistentVolume` is not applied from the template the `PersistentVolumeClaims` will fail. Please suggest a improvement if suppose i'm not using things in a right way.

Comment: It depends on what _type_ of storage you're trying to add. Typically, for production environments, you're using a StorageClass for a storage backend that has automatic PV provisioning. E.g., AWS EBS volumes. Obviously, that's not _always_ the case, but it is best practices. If you're using something painful, like an NFS volume mount, then you have no choice but to create the PV _and_ PVC.

Comment: Yes you are right, here i'm using NFS volume mount, hence i need to create PV and PVC.